# SQL : Left Join multiple time the same table with different types , Duplicates lines adding the value in it

Tags: sql, select, join, left-join

My problem is this query :

```
select 
  distinct 
  o1.id_personne,
  o1.id_table,
  tel.li_num_tel as Telephone,
  mail.li_url as EMail,
  fax.li_num_tel as Fax  
from table o1 
  Inner join personne p1 on 
    o1.id_personne = p1.id_personne 
  left join table_adresse a1 on
    o1.id_table = a1.id_table and 
    a1.co_type_adresse like 'TEL'
  left join table_adresse a2 on 
    o1.id_table = a2.id_table and 
    a2.co_type_adresse like 'NUM' 
  left join tabletel tel on 
    a1.id_table_tel = tel.id_table_tel and 
    tel.id_nature_adrtel = 1502 
  left join tabletel fax on 
    a1.id_table_tel = fax.id_table_tel and 
    fax.id_nature_adrtel = 1500
  left join tablenum mail on 
    a2.id_table_num = mail.id_table_num and 
    mail.id_nature_adrnum = 1400
where 
  p1.id_personne=1
```

This result:

```
|id_personne | id_table | telephone | email | Fax |
|1           | 5        | null      |test@te|null  |
|1           | 9        | null      |test@te|555 89|
|1           | 9        | 123 123 5 |test@te| null |
```

The value is correct for id 5 but id 9 is duplicated with different values it should return the 3 ( Email + tel + fax ) fields in the same line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following might work. The function `MAX` should ignore your nulls and therefore combine the duplicated rows when joining table_adresse to the telephone and fax tables

```
SELECT 
  distinct 
  o1.id_personne,
  o1.id_table,
  mail.li_url as EMail,
  X.li_num_tel as Fax  
  X.li_num_tel as Telephone,
from 
  table o1 
  Inner join personne p1 on 
    o1.id_personne = p1.id_personne 
  left join table_adresse a2 on 
    o1.id_table = a2.id_table and 
    a2.co_type_adresse like 'NUM'
  left join tablenum mail on 
    a2.id_table_num = mail.id_table_num and 
    mail.id_nature_adrnum = 1400
LEFT JOIN  
  (
  SELECT
    a1.id_table, 
    MAX(tel.li_num_tel) as Telephone,
    MAX(fax.li_num_tel) as Fax 
  FROM  table_adresse a1
    LEFT JOIN tabletel tel on 
      a1.id_table_tel = tel.id_table_tel and 
      tel.id_nature_adrtel = 1502 
    LEFT JOIN tabletel fax on 
      a1.id_table_tel = fax.id_table_tel and 
      fax.id_nature_adrtel = 1500
  WHERE co_type_adresse like 'TEL'
  GROUP BY a1.id_table
  ) X
  ON 
  o1.id_table = X.id_table
WHERE
  p1.id_personne=1
```

...or maybe in your original query you could just try this:

```
 select 
  o1.id_personne,
  o1.id_table,
  MAX(tel.li_num_tel) as Telephone,
  MAX(mail.li_url) as EMail,
  MAX(fax.li_num_tel) as Fax  
from table o1 
  Inner join personne p1 on 
    o1.id_personne = p1.id_personne 
  left join table_adresse a1 on
    o1.id_table = a1.id_table and 
    a1.co_type_adresse like 'TEL'
  left join table_adresse a2 on 
    o1.id_table = a2.id_table and 
    a2.co_type_adresse like 'NUM' 
  left join tabletel tel on 
    a1.id_table_tel = tel.id_table_tel and 
    tel.id_nature_adrtel = 1502 
  left join tabletel fax on 
    a1.id_table_tel = fax.id_table_tel and 
    fax.id_nature_adrtel = 1500
  left join tablenum mail on 
    a2.id_table_num = mail.id_table_num and 
    mail.id_nature_adrnum = 1400
where 
  p1.id_personne=1
GROUP BY
  o1.id_personne,
  o1.id_table
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have two rows in table `table_adresse` having `id_table = 9 AND co_type_adresse like 'TEL'`, with different values of `li_num_tel`.  Each one will combine with the same row of `table join personne` to produce a result row.  Because the result rows differ, both pass `DISTINCT` selection.

Comment: How could i make the joins goe on and dont let them combine each row with the rest , and combine them in one and same row as i dont get duplicated lines

Comment: @Stim, you cannot alter the way joins work.  Possibly you could better filter the result rows, or aggregate them, but only you can determine the appropriate way to do that to serve your particular purpose.  Alternatively, it may be that your data are simply wrong. I can (and did) tell you something about what your query results say about the base data, but only you can determine whether that indicates erroneous data.